# Can't using fusion chart with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fusioncharts, laravel-3

I use Laravel create graphs using fusion chart, but after I gave the script to call the chart turns laravel can not run a script that calls the url to get the data from the server process. But if I call the *.json file and I have tried it on raw php (without laravel) result is success. Is laravel prohibits view on my script to do the reading data via url?

My view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var chart = new FusionCharts("public/fusion/Charts/Column2D.swf", "ChartId",    "100%", "400", "0", "1");
        chart.setJSONUrl("http://api.bertho.web.id/grafik/tiket2.php"); <- Failed
        chart.setJSONUrl("public/fusion/data/data.json"); <- Success
        chart.render("chartdiv");
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the Laravel URI from browser, does this work as expected? Basically Laravel has nothing to with your frontend. I think you are mixing-up routes.

Comment: @Usman my route only : return View::make('home.index');  my index.blade.php fusion chart contains the script that I wrote above

Comment: `public/fusion/data/data.json` What does that mean? Is this a static file in public folder? Then remove `public` just `/fusion/data/data.json`.

Comment: 1. Probably due to cross domain data access. Or 2. The server is not set to serve Json mime type.